# Segmentation Violation Detected calling Matlab from .NET 2.0 application

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, matlab, c#-2.0

I am getting this error when I am trying to do some co variance calculations using Matlab. I am calling matlab from a .NET 2.0 application on win 2008 server 64 bit application. The exception message I get from matlab is **"Evaluation function error, SEGV: Severe error"**

```
I am copying the dump file from the matlab crash. Any help is really appreciated, thanks in advance.

This is the Exception information I see in the Dump file:

**"The Thread tried to read from or write to an virtual address for which it does not have the appropriate access"**

------------------------------------------------------------------------
       Segmentation violation detected at Thu Aug 22 15:05:20 2013
------------------------------------------------------------------------

Configuration:

  MATLAB Version:   7.9.0.529 (R2009b)
  MATLAB License:   unknown
  Operating System: Microsoft Windows Server Longhorn
  Window System:    Version 6.0 (Build 6002: Service Pack 2)
  Processor ID:     x86 Family 6 Model 14 Stepping 6, GenuineIntel
  Virtual Machine:  Java 1.6.0_45-b06 with Sun Microsystems Inc. Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
  Default Encoding:  windows-1252

Fault Count: 1

Register State:

  rax = 00000000c0000005      rbx = 0000000024c25e40
  rcx = 000000001f517950      rdx = 000000001f517108
  rbp = 0000000000000050      rsi = 0000000000000020
  rdi = 0000000000000000      rsp = 000000001f518750
   r8 = 000000001ed23000      r9 = ffffffffc0000005
  r10 = 000000001f518690      r11 = 000000001f517788
  r12 = 0000000076df54e3      r13 = 00000000fffffd66
  r14 = 0000000079f5d05d      r15 = 0000000079f5d05d
  rip = 000000001f518830      flg = 0000000000010202

Stack Trace:

  [  0] 0000000076CBAF46     KERNEL32.dll+110406 (FlsSetValue+000422)

  [  1] 0000000076CB1CF7     KERNEL32.dll+072951 (GetEnvironmentVariableA+000311)

  [  2] 000000007005DDB6     mkl.dll+384438 (xerbla+310678)

  [  3] 0000000079F5D05D     libmwmathlinalg.dll+249949 (mfMatrixMult+006973)

  [  4] 0000000024C25E40     libiomp5md.dll+024128 (kmp_set_defaults+015320)

  [  5] 000000007004EDAC     mkl.dll+322988 (xerbla+249228)

  [  6] 0000000074F1EC7F     MSVCR80.dll+191615 (mbsnbicoll_l+000351)

  [  7] 0000000074EF6DFB     MSVCR80.dll+028155 (free+000027)

  [  8] 0000000074F1CDEC     MSVCR80.dll+183788 (_crtGetStringTypeW+001724)

  [  9] 0000000074F524B3     MSVCR80.dll+402611 (makepath_s+000947)

  [ 10] 0000000024C2EB3B     libiomp5md.dll+060219 (ompc_set_num_threads+000031)

  [ 11] 000000007C8816A0     libmwblas.dll+071328 (ztrsv+027816)

  [ 12] 000000007C8817C0     libmwblas.dll+071616 (ztrsv+028104)

  [ 13] 000000007C857B45     libmwbinder.dll+031557 (Binder::_load_and_resolve+001445)

  [ 14] 000000007C8816A0     libmwblas.dll+071328 (ztrsv+027816)

  [ 15] 0000000076E19915     ntdll.dll+301333 (AlpcGetMessageAttribute+002309)

  [ 16] 0000000079FFA250     libmwmathlinalg.dll+893520 (SparseLUFactor::`vftable'+004576)

  [ 17] 0000000079FFA24C     libmwmathlinalg.dll+893516 (SparseLUFactor::`vftable'+004572)

 [ 18] 000000007CEC9272     libmx.dll+037490 (mxCharMatrixToStrings_UTF8+000194)
```

Comment: You may want to post your question to the [matlab forum](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader) where matlab devs answer such question, or directly request help from the [help menu](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/contact-technical-support.html).

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I have no idea what's causing your error or how to fix it.

But MATLAB should *never* SEGV like this. Even if you've done something bad or unsupported, it should error gracefully and tell you what went wrong.

If you can reproducibly get this SEGV error, report it to MathWorks as a bug. They may or may not be able to find out whether you were doing something wrong, and may or may not be able to suggest a workaround or solution - but they need to know about the SEGV.

When reporting the issue to MathWorks, if possible report a minimal reproducible case, and do make sure to describe all aspects of the system (OS, MATLAB, .NET etc).